# NuGet for Kendo.Mvc.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.MVC and [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/) for my web application.

Currently, I've this code:

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
// do something
}
```

`DataSourceRequest` is available in `Kendo.Mvc.dll`. Currently, I got the .dll from [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/export-grid-to-excel.aspx) site.

My question is where I can get this dll from NuGet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Nuget Package for Kendo MVC.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/nuget-install-for-kendoui-mvc.aspx

> I am afraid we do not plan to create a NuGet version for Kendo UI for
>   ASP.NET MVC. The reason is that such product is not available under an
>   open source license.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a nuget version available for licensed users:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/nuget-package-update

Comment: Hi Phil..just want to ask that kendo.mvc.dll is available from nuget? could you provide search keyword from nuget? Becuase i tried to use `Kendo.MVC` by Telerik from nuget but still i am getting error in `@Html.Kendo()`